# ReactiveUI Command chain

Tags: c#, reactiveui

I do need to execute one command after another, thing I'm trying to do:

```
FirstCommnand.Select(_ => Unit.Default).InvokeCommand(SecondCommand);
```

But neither `Select`, nor `InvokeCommand` called.

What am I missing?

Comment: It's working fine for me. Can you confirm that FirstCommand executes?`FirstCommand.Subscribe(_ => Console.WriteLine("FirstCommand"));`

Comment: Yes, command is executed, also subscription works fine